# wildfly 8 + jersey war file deployment issues

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jersey-2.0, wildfly

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to figure out.  I can't seem to deploy the application successfully to wildfly, and it's not giving me much detail to try and rectify the issue.  Here is the deployment error from wildfly console:

```
17:57:24,735 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-9) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.CR1.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ServiceLocator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject private org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.PersistenceUnitBinder$PersistenceUnitInjectionResolver(ServiceLocator)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.PersistenceUnitBinder$PersistenceUnitInjectionResolver.<init>(PersistenceUnitInjectionResolver.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:361)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:282)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:133)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:507)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    ... 3 more

17:57:24,742 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "iamws.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"iamws.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"iamws.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ServiceLocator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject private org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.PersistenceUnitBinder$PersistenceUnitInjectionResolver(ServiceLocator)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.PersistenceUnitBinder$PersistenceUnitInjectionResolver.<init>(PersistenceUnitInjectionResolver.java:0)
"}}
17:57:24,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "ojdbc6.jar" (runtime-name : "ojdbc6.jar")
17:57:24,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "iamws.war" (runtime-name : "iamws.war")
17:57:24,795 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service

17:57:24,801 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
17:57:24,801 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
17:57:24,801 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.0.0.CR1 "WildFly" started (with errors) in 7749ms - Started 304 of 385 services (21 services failed or missing dependencies, 95 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
17:57:25,020 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = iamws.war_oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver_11_2
17:57:25,022 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'iamws.war#iamwsDev'
17:57:25,024 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment iamws.war
17:57:25,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'iamws.war#iamwsDev'
17:57:25,067 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment iamws.war (runtime-name: iamws.war) in 50ms
17:57:25,107 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "iamws.war" (runtime-name: "iamws.war")
17:57:25,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator, JBAS014799: ... and 7 more ] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator, JBAS014799: ... and 5 more ] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."ca.ubc.iamws.listeners.ServiceContextListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."ca.ubc.iamws.listeners.ServiceContextListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."ca.ubc.iamws.listeners.ServiceContextListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."ca.ubc.iamws.listeners.ServiceContextListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."ca.ubc.iamws.listeners.ServiceContextListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."ca.ubc.iamws.listeners.ServiceContextListener".START] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."iamws.war#iamwsDev" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".component."ca.ubc.iamws.listeners.ServiceContextListener".START] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./iamws] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."iamws.war".WeldStartService

17:57:29,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found iamws.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called iamws.war.dodeploy
```

and here is my pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ca.ubc.iamws</groupId>
  <artifactId>iamws</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>IAMS Web Service</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.5.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <hibernate-core-version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-core-version>
        <codi.version>1.0.5</codi.version>
        <target.dir>target</target.dir>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  jackson dependencies for pojo/json support -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end jackson deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit test and jersey client features -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--  Weld/CDI Begin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>iamws</finalName>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/${target.dir}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/${target.dir}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>src/test/*</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                <pluginExecutions>
                    <!-- copy-dependency plugin -->
                    <pluginExecution>
                        <pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                            <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <action>
                            <ignore />
                        </action>
                    </pluginExecution>
                </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>eclipse-folders</id>
      <properties>
        <target.dir>target-eclipse</target.dir>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Never used jersey with wildfly, but it might conflict with the resteasy module that comes with the distribution. Do you specifically exclude this from the deployment?

Comment: Yes, I did.  I removed the extensions in the various files (standalone.xml, module.xml) - made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found, Jersey is no longer a viable option for use with Wildfly. I had all sorts of hassles trying to get a Jersey App deployed to Wildfly 8.2.0. The [Imixs Workflow project explain](http://blog.imixs.org/how-to-migrate-from-glassfish-to-wildfly/) how they migrated their app from Glassfish to Wildfly and had to reconfigure their **web.xml** for deployment using RestEasy (being a rest app).

In essence:

> Using RestServices makes it necessary to change things in the web.xml file because Jersey (used by GlassFish) and RestEasy (used by Wildfly) have  different configurations.

This worked for my Rest App; and it was finally able to deploy.